# rownumber(nothing) - skip lines

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm using `rownumber(nothing)` to create numbering on my report.
I have subheadings for GROUP AVERAGE inside my dataset.
Where I use a background expression to set all rows above GROUP AVERAGE Green, below Red, and the line containing GROUP AVERAGE I leave white.

```
=IIF(Fields!Dealer.Value = "GROUP AVERAGE","",RowNumber(Nothing))
```

My problem is that `Rownumber` is not skipping the GROUP AVERAGE line, and I have a situation like this

```
1  Store A        80%  
2  Store B        78%  
3  Store C        60%  
   ### GROUP AVERAGE  50% ###  
5  Store D        40%  
6  Store E        30%   
...
```

I want Store D to be number 4, not 5.

Comment: The logic is simple: Subtract one from the rownumber If the value is below average.

Answer (score 0):

```
runningvalue(Fields!YOURVALUE.Value,count,nothing)
```